# método node.appendChild() añade un elemento en el mismo lugar Javascript

Tags: javascript, script, javascript-objeto, div, setinterval

Estoy intentando implementar un script en el que el circulo rojo se vaya agregando de izquierda a derecha, o de arriba hacia abajo cada un segundo hasta que se presione el botón "stop".

El código en general funciona, el problema que estoy teniendo es que el circulo rojo se agrega constantemente pero en el mismo lugar, es decir, no se va agregando uno debajo del otro (al ser un elemento de bloque, pense que iba a funcionar de esa forma).

Mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Por que el elemento "div" se agrega siempre en el mismo lugar?.
2. ¿Existe alguna forma en la que pueda generar uno debajo del otro, o uno a lado de otro?.

Este es el código html y javascript que estoy usando (no es algo que vaya a aplicar en la vida real, simplemente estoy practicando las características de javascript):

```js
var divNode = document.getElementById("caja");
var buttonNode = document.getElementById("button1");
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

function appendDiv(){
    if(divNode != null){
        divNode.appendChild(newDiv);
    }else{
        console.log("div node is null");
    }
}

if(buttonNode != null){
    buttonNode.addEventListener("click", function(){
        clearInterval(intervalFaceID);
    }, false);
}else{
    console.log("button node is null");
}

var intervalFaceID = setInterval(appendDiv, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Objetos Window - interval añadiendo objetos</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        body{
            background-color: #cccccc;
        }

        div{
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #af0000;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .content{
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
            margin: 50px auto;

            width: 400px;
            height: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-radius: 1px;
            box-shadow: #000000 0px 0px 5px 3px;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #232526, #414345);
        }
        #caja{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        p{
            font-size: 2em;
        }
        button{
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            margin-right: 7px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- here -->

<div class="content">
    <div id="caja"></div>
    <button id="button1">Stop</button>
</div>

<!-- -->

<script src="scripts/Objetos-Window-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perdón, seguí indagando y me di cuenta de que el elemento div tiene que crearse en cada llamada a la función "appendDiv" para que se cree en cada ocasión en la que se llama a esa función. Solucionado

Comment: Correcto. Estabas metiendo siempre el mismo div, y ahora creas uno nuevo cada vez, que se añade tal como esperabas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entiendo es que intentas agregar varios círculos rojos uno al lado del otro.

No funciona porque solo estas creando un solo circulo rojo(div) lo que tienes que hacer es crear uno nuevo en cada llamado a la función `appendDiv()`

Entonces deberias poner esta linea `var newDiv = document.createElement("div");` pero dentro de tu función `appendDiv()`